# What does Sharepoint Standard Server 2010 search offer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, search

I will be deploying a SharePoint Intranet using SP Standard 2010.
I know i have to pay for FAST search if i want to use it.The only option i have to create a search site is Basic Search Center  which is under Enterprise tab.
Is that all i get under Standard version? Or i need to do some setup get something advanced.
Just confirming.
Thanks i advance
** If you have any resource you can forward me to on hwo to connfigure search for SP Standard Server 2010 i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to see the differences between Standard and Enterprise features is at http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/pages/editions-comparison.aspx . Click on the "Search" filter and it will narrow the list down to what you are interested in. Standard Edition offers a lot.

Here is the TechNet page for configuring search: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee808863.aspx

Comment: Thanks Rob.But on MSDN it says:
In the Template Selection section, click the Enterprise tab and then select the Enterprise Search Center template or the Basic Search Center template. If you intend to use people search, you must select the Enterprise Search Center template. Unlike the Basic Search Center, the Enterprise Search Center provides a tab for people search.
 
But i don't get to see the Enterprise Search Center to be able to create one.Is this because im not using Sharepoint Enterprise version? Or i need to enable it.

Comment: This is a tough call. Enabling Enterprise features could cause a licensing issue for you, yet all of the features  that Standard edition claims to include may not be there unless you do. I'll have to defer to someone who knows more about it than me.